# How to search entires containg multiple word prefixes in a multi-column fulltext index in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb, full-text-search, innodb

I have a table storing person names

```sql
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `first_name_last_name` (`first_name`,`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `person` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
('Aristide',    'Romano'),
('Jérôme',  'Nadeau'),
('Madeleine',   'Roger'),
('Daniel',  'De Jong'),
('Alban',   'Hervé'),
('Camille', 'Evrard'),
('Delphine',    'Vriaud'),
('Pavel',   'Lelièvre'),
('Albert',  'De Vries'),
('Luc', 'Robin'),
('Vanessa', 'Olivier'),
('Georges', 'De Vries'),
('Delphine', 'Bernard');
```

*Note : these are en extract from randomly generated names, not actual people.*

When the user searches for "de vr", I want to return all lines containing a word starting with "de" **and** a word starting with "vr" :

- **De**lphine **Vr**iaud
- Albert **De** **Vr**ies
- Georges **De** **Vr**ies

The real table is of course much bigger (around 10,000 lines), and the query will be used quite often, which is why I'm trying to use a FULLTEXT search instead of the heavy `column LIKE "{search}%"`

I can't use the default "order by relevance" from fulltext search because a custom ORDER BY clause is always applied based on user input. I need the query to return those lines **only** because I can't expect the good results to appear at the top if they are diluted in partial matches.

Based on [the operators description in MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-text-index-overview/#in-boolean-mode), I supposed the right way to do this would be :

```sql
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('+de*, +vr*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

The `*` means "I accept this word or words starting like this..." and the "+" means "All results must match this word".

But this query returns "Delphine Vriaud" only. It seems the matches have to be in different columns, preventing the last name "De Vries" from matching.

If I remove the `+` signs from the query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('de*, vr*'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

I get all lines containing either "de*" or "vr*", as expected, which includes the 3 lines I want **and** "Delphine Bernard" I don't want.

You may try the queries [on this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0b7b5/1).

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with FULLTEXT search ?

EDIT : I found out afterwards about the InnoDB variable [innodb_ft_min_token_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_ft_min_token_size) which defines the minimum length a word must have to be included in a FULLTEXT index. The default value of this variable is 3, which means the word "De" from "De Vries" or "De Jong" is not in the index and could explain the results.

I've changed the value to 2 on my local MariaDb server and tried again, but the results didn't change.

Comment: Do you want to catch `Vrxyz Deabc`?  Or only when `De` comes before ``Vr` in `first last`?

Answer (score 1):

- Change `innodb_ft_min_token_size` to 2 and rebuild the index.
- `MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('+de* +vr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` -- `+` for both "words"

Comment: I didn't know I had to rebuild the index, thanks. I must be missing something, though. `SHOW VARIABLES` shows that `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is set to 2. I've tried to rebuild the index both with `OPTIMIZE TABLE` and a dummy `ALTER`. I've also deleted and recreated the index, just to be sure. And yet none of this changes the result.

Comment: Another thing...  If half the rows have "De", that "word" may be ignored when building the index.  So, add some more sample data before testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('de* +vr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE MATCH (first_name, last_name) AGAINST ('de*,+vr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

Comment: Watch out for `innodb_ft_min_token_size`.  If it is set to the default of `3`, then `De` will not be indexed.  And rebuild the index after changing the value.